# Using ifelse to produce ggplot: longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Tags: r, object, if-statement, ggplot2

I have a data frame called Completed that looks something like this:

```
X1 Latitude Longitude Conservation
1     40        -8         Yes
2     -5        10         No
3     20        30         Yes
4      5        -10        No
```

I would like to generate a very simple plot with points on a world map that are color-coded based on whether Conservation = Yes or No. Here is the code I tried:

```
world <- map_data("world")
gg1 <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = world, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3)


labs <- data.frame(
  long = Completed$Longitude,
  lat = Completed$Latitude,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )  


ID.list <- unique(Completed$X1)
for (X1 in ID.list) {


  ifelse(Completed$Conservation %in% 'Yes',  gg1  +
  geom_point(data = labs, aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "yellow", size = 2),  gg1  +
  geom_point(data = labs, aes(x = long, y = lat), color = "pink", size = 2)) 

  }
```

This generates the error: "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

I'm very new to R so I'm struggling to understand what this issue means and how to fix my code. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: use `aes(color = Conservation)` instead of a `for` loop.

Full solution:

```
Completed <- tribble(
~X1, ~Latitude, ~Longitude, ~Conservation,
1,     40,        -8,         "Yes",
2,     -5,        10,         "No",
3,     20,        30,         "Yes",
4,      5,        -10,        "No"
)

world <- map_data("world")
gg1 <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = world, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(1.3)

gg1 + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, color = Conservation), 
                 data = Completed, size = 2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("pink", "yellow"))
```